# How to update values for several columns in a Table with a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table something like below,

**ID   Name   EMail   Gender**

and there are values already in this table.

Now, I used below query to add age.

*alter table tblPerson add Age int*

Now, my row structure looks like

**ID  Name  EMail  gender  Age**

Now, I have list of ages. Any query to add these ages into newly created column?

All the ages are sorted according to ID. So no IF logic required. I just need to add column data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Store the values in a temporary table with the id.  Then use a `join`:

```
update t join
       idages ia
       on t.id = io.id
    set t.age = ia.age;
```

You can also do this with a giant `case` expression, but that is prone to error:

```
update t
    set t.age = (case when id = id1 then age1
                      when id = id2 then age2
                      when id = id3 then age3
                      . . .
                 end)
    where t.age in (id1, id2, id3, . . .);
```